# ¿Es posible evitar alguna clave del array usando json_encode o cómo limpiar el resultado?

Tags: php, json

Estoy creando un JSON a partir de unos resultados obtenidos de la base de datos.

El array de resultados es algo así:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id_tiempo] => 8
        [id_tipo] => 50
        [dia] => 7
        [semana] => 27
        [id_color] => 
        [la_meta] => 0101010301010101
        [cod_liturgia] => 313
        [santo] => 
        [vida] => 
        [antifona_i] => Del Señor es la tierra y cuanto la llena; venid, adorémosle.
        [himno] => Cantemos al Señor con indecible gozo,~él guarde la esperanza de nuestro corazón,~dejemos la inquietud posar entre sus manos,~abramos nuestro espíritu a su infinito amor.§Dichoso será aquel que siempre en él confía~en horas angustiosas de lucha y de aflicción,~confiad en el Señor si andáis atribulados,~abramos nuestro espíritu a su infinito amor.§Los justos saben bien que Dios siempre nos ama,~en penas y alegrías su paz fue su bastión,~la fuerza del Señor fue gloria en sus batallas,~abramos nuestro espíritu a su infinito amor.§Envíanos, Señor, tu luz esplendorosa~si el alma se acongoja en noche y turbación,~qué luz, qué dulce paz en Dios el hombre encuentra;~abramos nuestro espíritu a su infinito amor.§Recibe, Padre santo, el ruego y la alabanza,~que a ti, por Jesucristo y por el Consolador,~dirige en comunión tu amada y santa Iglesia;~abramos nuestro espíritu a su infinito amor. Amén.
        [json] => {"salmos":[{"orden":"3", 
"antifona":"La fidelidad del Señor dura por siempre.",
"ref":"Salmo 116",
"tema":"Invitación universal a la alabanza divina",
"intro":"Así es: los gentiles~glorifican a Dios por su misericordia.~(Rm 15, 8. 9)",
"parte":"",
"salmo":"Alabad al Señor, todas las naciones,_aclamadlo, todos los pueblos:§Firme es su misericordia con nosotros,_su fidelidad dura por siempre."},{"orden":"2", 
"antifona":"Mándame tu sabiduría, Señor, para que me asista en mis trabajos.",
"ref":"Cántico¦Sb 9, 1-6. 9-11",
"tema":"Dame, Señor, la Sabiduría",
"intro":"Os daré palabras y sabiduría~a las que no podrá hacer frente...~ningún adversario vuestro.~(Lc 21, 15)",
"parte":"",
"salmo":"Dios de los padres y Señor de la misericordia,_que con tu palabra hiciste todas las cosas,_y en tu sabiduría formaste al hombre,_para que dominase sobre tus creaturas,_y para que rigiese el mundo con santidad y justicia_y lo gobernase con rectitud de corazón.§Dame la sabiduría asistente de tu trono_y no me excluyas del número de tus siervos,_porque siervo tuyo soy, hijo de tu sierva,_hombre débil y de pocos años,_demasiado pequeño para conocer el juicio y las leyes.§Pues aunque uno sea perfecto_entre los hijos de los hombres,_sin la sabiduría, que procede de ti,_será estimado en nada.§Contigo está la sabiduría conocedora de tus obras,_que te asistió cuando hacías el mundo,_y que sabe lo que es grato a tus ojos_y lo que es recto según tus preceptos.§Mándala de tus santos cielos_y de tu trono de gloria envíala_para que me asista en mis trabajos_y venga yo a saber lo que te es grato.§Porque ella conoce y entiende todas las cosas,_y me guiará prudentemente en mis obras,_y me guardará en su esplendor."},{"orden":"1", 
"antifona":"Tú, Señor, estás cerca, y todos tus mandatos son estables.",
"ref":"Salmo 118, 145-152",
"tema":"",
"intro":"",
"parte":"",
"salmo":"Te invoco de todo corazón;_respóndeme, Señor, y guardaré tus leyes;_a ti grito: sálvame,_y cumpliré tus decretos;_me adelanto a la aurora pidiendo auxilio,_esperando tus palabras.§Mis ojos se adelantan a las vigilias de la noche,_meditando tu promesa;_escucha mi voz por tu misericordia,_con tus mandamientos dame vida;_ya se acercan mis inicuos perseguidores,_están lejos de tu voluntad.§Tú, Señor, estás cerca,_y todos tus mandatos son estables;_hace tiempo comprendí que tus preceptos_los fundaste para siempre."}]}
        [ordenes] => 1|2|3

   ....
```

Ahora yo quiero crear un JSON a partir de mi array, pero excluyendo la clave llamada `json`.

El problema es que esta clave es ya un `json` y yo quiero producir un JSON limpio. Si lo incluyo directamente, se me crea así:

```
{
    "json": "{\"salmos\":[{\"orden\":\"3\", \n    \"antifona\":\"La fidelidad del Señor dura por siempre.\",\n    \"ref\":\"Salmo 116\",\n    \"tema\":\"Invitación universal a la alabanza divina\",\n    \"intro\":\"Así es: los gentiles~glorifican a Dios por su misericordia.~(Rm 15, 8. 9)\",\n    \"parte\":\"\",\n    \"salmo\":\"Alabad al Señor, todas las naciones,_aclamadlo, todos los pueblos:§Firme es su misericordia con nosotros,_su fidelidad dura por siempre.\"},{\"orden\":\"2\", \n    \"antifona\":\"Mándame tu sabiduría, Señor, para que me asista en mis trabajos.\",\n    \"ref\":\"Cántico¦Sb 9, 1-6. 9-11\",\n    \"tema\":\"Dame, Señor, la Sabiduría\",\n    \"intro\":\"Os daré palabras y sabiduría~a las que no podrá hacer frente...~ningún adversario vuestro.~(Lc 21, 15)\",\n    \"parte\":\"\",\n    \"salmo\":\"Dios de los padres y Señor de la misericordia,_que con tu palabra hiciste todas las cosas,_y en tu sabiduría formaste al hombre,_para que dominase sobre tus creaturas,_y para que rigiese el mundo con santidad y justicia_y lo gobernase con rectitud de corazón.§Dame la sabiduría asistente de tu trono_y no me excluyas del número de tus siervos,_porque siervo tuyo soy, hijo de tu sierva,_hombre débil y de pocos años,_demasiado pequeño para conocer el juicio y las leyes.§Pues aunque uno sea perfecto_entre los hijos de los hombres,_sin la sabiduría, que procede de ti,_será estimado en nada.§Contigo está la sabiduría conocedora de tus obras,_que te asistió cuando hacías el mundo,_y que sabe lo que es grato a tus ojos_y lo que es recto según tus preceptos.§Mándala de tus santos cielos_y de tu trono de gloria envíala_para que me asista en mis trabajos_y venga yo a saber lo que te es grato.§Porque ella conoce y entiende todas las cosas,_y me guiará prudentemente en mis obras,_y me guardará en su esplendor.\"},{\"orden\":\"1\", \n    \"antifona\":\"Tú, Señor, estás cerca, y todos tus mandatos son estables.\",\n    \"ref\":\"Salmo 118, 145-152\",\n    \"tema\":\"\",\n    \"intro\":\"\",\n    \"parte\":\"\",\n    \"salmo\":\"Te invoco de todo corazón;_respóndeme, Señor, y guardaré tus leyes;_a ti grito: sálvame,_y cumpliré tus decretos;_me adelanto a la aurora pidiendo auxilio,_esperando tus palabras.§Mis ojos se adelantan a las vigilias de la noche,_meditando tu promesa;_escucha mi voz por tu misericordia,_con tus mandamientos dame vida;_ya se acercan mis inicuos perseguidores,_están lejos de tu voluntad.§Tú, Señor, estás cerca,_y todos tus mandatos son estables;_hace tiempo comprendí que tus preceptos_los fundaste para siempre.\"}]}"
}
```

Y yo lo quiero totalmente limpio.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo con `json_encode`?

He probado con esto:

```
$json=json_encode($rows,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Pero no obtengo el resultado esperado.

### Algunas aclaraciones a raíz de los comentarios

- Yo necesito un JSON final que incluya también la información que hay en la clave `json`
- El orden no importa, pero si queda en la posición en que está mucho mejor
- Lo que me lleva a no querer poner directamente el contenido de la clave `json` en el objeto JSON final son todos los símbolos de este tipo `\` que se añaden en el resultado. No sé, yo podría extraerlos de alguna manera, pero estoy buscando algo simple y que funcione lo más rápido dado que el JSON alimenta una aplicación con tráfico considerable a nivel mundial y no quiero sobrecargar demasiado el código que obtiene ese dato.

Comment: Podés quitarlo con unset($elArray['json']) y después hacer el json_enconde

Comment: quieres eliminar del array el elemento "json"?

Comment: No lo quiero eliminar. Lo añadiré aparte al JSON final @PabloMoraga

Comment: No hace falta que uses el mismo array, simplemente copialo y remueve el elemento en el segundo.

Comment: Se me ocurre  un par de firmas de hacerlo, pero dependiendo de json que traes quizás lo más simple seria hacerle un decode reescribiendo la clave. Me explico: `$arr['json'] = json_decode($arr['json']);` luego ya codificas todo el Array. Como nota, almacenar datos en la base de datos como json es una mala práctica.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, tu lo que quieres hacer es "aplanar" el Array, para que todas las `keys`que aparecen en la propiedad `json`, pasen delante.

```
function array_flatten($array) {
   $return = array();
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
       if (is_array($value)){ $return = array_merge($return, array_flatten($value));}
       else {$return[$key] = $value;}
   }
   return $return;
}
$aplanado = array_flatten($rows);
$resultado = json_encode($aplanado ,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Esto te funciona con cualquier subnivel.

Comment: No puedo comentarte aún, pero he visto en los otros comentarios, que tu lo que buscas son 2 resultados, uno con todo el json menos la clave "json" y otro solo con los valores internos de esa clave pero sin ella ¿no?

Comment: No. Yo quiero todo el contenido de la clave `json` en el resultado final. Solo que si lo incluyo directamente me crea símbolos que no quiero. La idea es, dado que la clave `json` es un objeto JSON en sí, crear el JSON con los otros elementos y luego agregarle los valores de la clave `json` directamente. El orden en que queden no tiene mucha importancia, aunque si queda bien ordenado mejor.

Comment: Entonces mi respuesta debe valer, te pone los valores del `$rows.json` al mismo nivel que los de `$rows`,  y luego te hace el json_encode. ¿Puedes poner el Array sin var_dump para probar en mi servidor?